# jquery .click doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I hope I'm not just making a stupid mistake, but For some reason, the following code doesn't work. The only thing that happens is it logs "ready" in the console, but not anything within the .click

Javascript:

```
var Photobooth = (function (){
var api = {};

var init = function(){
    form_ready();

};


var form_ready = function(){
    console.log("ready");
    $('#btn-signin').click(function(e){


        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('click');

        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "entertainment/photobooth/signin/action/",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
              success: function(){
                $(this).addClass("done");
              }
            });

    });
};



init();
return api;
})();
```

HTML:

```
<a id="btn-signin" href="##">SIGN IN </a>
```

THE SOLUTION: Normally, I put my JS code at the end of the document, before the closing body... In this case I had to put it in the beginning and forgot to put the document.ready, so it works now. Thanks

Comment: Just tried it in Chrome, it seems to work fine (I get "click" logged in the console): http://jsfiddle.net/SzwRe/

Comment: You have a lot of unnecessary code, it's better to create a reduction of your problem. you api variable gets returned, but it's an empty object.

Comment: It works for me. Is your javascript running before the document is ready?

Comment: @Juan, yes, this is only a snippet... there is more that uses the api object

Comment: that's my point, you removed some but left a bunch of irrelevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the document.ready wrapper:

```
var Photobooth = $(function (){...
  ....
  init();
  return api;
});
```

Comment: Wow.... I'm not sure why that missed it... I've never put a document.ready wrapper and it has always worked. Maybe because it's at the top of the page actually... yea that makes sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/NiceGuy4263/LchcF/2/

In my example you'll see that I wrapped you code in the jQuery ready function.

Answer (score 0):

It does work for me. Try a demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tuKLL/):

I assume your jQuery is not loaded before you use it.

Always use jQuery within

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you are calling your code before `<a>` is created. Use jQuery's `ready` or move your code to bottom of the page.